# Work done in case of an accelerating object

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, work, homework-and-exercises

How do you calculate work when opposing force is less than applied force. So a 5 N static friction force is overcome by 15 N manual force for say 5 meter. What is the work done by manual force?

Comment: Conceptually, this is about as easy as it gets:  There is a **15N manual force applied through 5 meters**.  The **work done by the manual force** is...  (evidently, Floris types faster than I do)

Comment: @AlfredCentauri - yep, apparently so. But great minds thinking alike.

Comment: @Floris that should probably be an answer.

Comment: @AlfredCentauri cc above

Answer (score 1):

If the force applied is greater than the friction, it just means that the object will accelerate. Some of the work goes into overcoming friction, the rest goes into accelerating the object (and thus kinetic energy). Work done by the force (15 N in your case) is just force times distance - it doesn't matter how that work is then split between the friction and kinetic energy.

Comment: thanks so much this helps :) I am trying to understand work done by different thermodynamic processes and that making me crazy :(

Comment: Great - couldn't agree more - work done = Force $\times$ distance - or could put as $\int$ Force dx - nice comment about being able to work out how much energy goes into Kinetic Energy - guess the rest will go into heat through the friction.

Comment: So it is fair to say that best buck for your money is to apply force slowly and just little more than opposing force to do the maximum work. If you apply more force sure you will do work but you are going to waste lot of work in heat etc.? and that is the rational behind reversible processes in thermodynamics.? slowly and force external always matching force internal

Comment: If your goal is to overcome the friction, then applying more force than needed will result in energy going into other processes (for example, kinetic energy of the object). Not sure that that will result in heat unless you keep pushing until the object hits a wall or in some other way loses that kinetic energy "irreversibly". In general with problems such as this, you just want to think about all the different places where energy goes - knowing that their sum is always preserved (if it's not, you have forgotten something - usually a loss mechanism).